# Multiple Dates Ranges in Sql Select Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, c#-4.0

I am currently working on C# with Sql Server Language, trying to design a query where I have to select quarters(Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4).

My issue is that, suppose if the user from the front end selects only Q1 then I can set the query to date range for quarter Q1, and if the user selects Q1 and as well Q2 then I can still set the date range for Q1 and Q2 because they fall under sequence date ranges.

But if the user selects Q1 and Q3 then how do I prepare date range query(either in stored procedure or simple select query) and excecute for this.

I was trying with this but no use.

```
where CDate in(cdate between '2015-05-20' and '2015-06-01' 
  and CDate between '2016-06-03' and '2016-06-04'

select * from MM  where @innerstring
```

The @innerstring I want to send as a parameter to the sql stored procedure and then prepare/execute it.
but I don't want to use temp table to store query data for saperate date ranges and then union that result. because I have different parameters with me as well.

Thanks.

Comment: Why the MySQL tag?

Comment: You have to add example data and expected result, we do not fully understand what you would like to do with quaters or dates.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need the `in`.  This should work:

```
where (cdate between '2015-05-20' and '2015-06-01' or
       cdate between '2016-06-03' and '2016-06-04'
      )
```

Note that `between` with dates can be dangerous/midleading, as Aaron Bertrand explains in an interesting [blog](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).  I would go for:

```
where (cdate >= '2015-05-20' and cdate < '2015-06-02' or
       cdate >= '2016-06-03' and cdate < '2016-06-05'
      )
```

This safely works even when `cdate` has a time component.

Comment: Nop its just selecting the records for the first date range after or its doing nothing. I want to include the result for both the date ranges, I mean select all records from cdate >= '2015-05-20' and cdate < '2015-06-02' and then include the result from cdate >= '2016-06-03' and cdate < '2016-06-05' aswell.

Comment: Yes thanks. I worked now. but how do I prepare it in SQL Query, I am selecting the Q1 through Q4 randomly, so how do I prepare the query based on my situation. The query has to be in sql stored procedure.

Comment: **Gordon Linoff**, Any idea about above.

Comment: I would add some parenthesis for better readability:  `where ((cdate >= '2015-05-20' and cdate < '2015-06-02') or
       (cdate >= '2016-06-03' and cdate < '2016-06-05')
      )`

Comment: How do I make the entire where clause in stored procedure to replace with string value. like above I just edited.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select date ranges based on quarters, you could use a calendar table to facilitate that. The following example uses snippets from [Creating a date dimension or calendar table in SQL Server - Aaron Bertrand](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/).

```
-- if regional settings are interfering with interpretation of dates/literals:
/*
set datefirst 7;
set dateformat mdy;
set language us_english;
--*/
if object_id('dbo.Calendar_Example') is not null drop table dbo.Calendar_Example;
create table dbo.Calendar_Example (
    [Date]         date     not null
  , [Year]         smallint not null
  , [Day]          tinyint  not null
  , [Month]        tinyint  not null
  , [Quarter]      tinyint  not null
  , [YearQuarter]  char(7)  not null /* yyyy-qq */
  , constraint pk_Calendar_Quarters primary key clustered (date)
  );

declare @FromDate date = '20160101';
declare @ThruDate date = '20201231';

with n as (select n from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) t(n))
, d as (
  select DateValue=convert(date,dateadd(day
      , row_number() over (order by (select 1)) -1, @fromdate))
    from         n as deka
      cross join n as hecto
      cross join n as kilo     /* 2.73 years */
      cross join n as [10k]    /* 27.3 years */
      --cross join n as [100k] /* 273  years */
      --cross join n as mega
)
insert into dbo.Calendar_Example 
    ([Date], [Year], [Day], [Month], [Quarter], [YearQuarter])
  select top (datediff(day, @FromDate, @ThruDate)+1) 
      [Date]        = DateValue
    , [Year]        = convert(smallint,datepart(year,DateValue))
    , [Day]         = convert(tinyint,datepart(day,DateValue)) 
    , [Month]       = convert(tinyint,datepart(month,DateValue)) 
    , [Quarter]     = convert(tinyint,datepart(quarter,DateValue)) 
    , [YearQuarter] = convert(char(7) ,convert(char(4), datepart(year,DateValue))
                      +'-Q'+convert(char(1), datepart(quarter,DateValue)))
    from d
    order by DateValue;
```

calendar and numbers tables reference:

- [Generate a set or sequence without loops - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1)
- [Creating a Date Table/Dimension in SQL Server 2008 - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/06/creating-a-date-tabledimension-for-sql-server-2008/)
- [Calendar Tables - Why You Need One - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/04/calendar-tables-why-you-need-one/)
- [Creating a date dimension or calendar table in SQL Server - Aaron Bertrand](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/)
- [TSQL Function to Determine Holidays in SQL Server - Tim Cullen](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1537/tsql-function-to-determine-holidays-in-sql-server/)
- [F_TABLE_DATE - Michael Valentine Jones](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=61519)

---

From there, you could use a **table valued parameter** (TVP) to pass a set of quarters to include in the select. Example:

```
create type dbo.YearQuarter_udt as table (
    YearQuarter char(7) not null
  , primary key (YearQuarter)
    );
go

create procedure dbo.Select_Using_YearQuarter_udt (
    @YearQuarter dbo.YearQuarter_udt readonly
) as
begin;
  set nocount on;
  set xact_abort on;
  with c as (
    select ce.[Date] 
      from dbo.Calendar_Example ce  
        inner join @YearQuarter yq on yq.YearQuarter = ce.YearQuarter
      )
  select *
    from MM
      inner join c  on mm.CDate = c.Date;
end;
go
```

If you want to pass a series of date ranges, you could do something like this:

```
create type dbo.DateRange_udt as table (
    FromDate date not null
  , ThruDate date not null
  primary key (FromDate,ThruDate)
    );
go

create procedure dbo.Select_Using_DateRange_udt (
    @DateRange dbo.DateRange_udt readonly
) as
begin;
  set nocount on;
  set xact_abort on;
  select *
    from MM
      inner join @DateRange dr on mm.CDate >= dr.FromDate 
                              and mm.CDate <= dr.ThruDate
end;
go
```

table valued parameter reference:

- [SQL Server 2008 Table-Valued Parameters and C# Custom Iterators: A Match Made In Heaven! - Leonard Lobel](https://lennilobel.wordpress.com/2009/07/29/sql-server-2008-table-valued-parameters-and-c-custom-iterators-a-match-made-in-heaven/)
- [Using Table Valued Parameters in Entity Framework - Ritesh Sharma](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/78607b/using-table-valued-parameters-in-entity-framework/)
- [Using Table-Valued Parameters in SQL Server and .NET - Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html)
- [how to use TVPs with Entity Framework 4.1 and CodeFirst](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/179481/Code-First-Stored-Procedures)
- [Maximizing Performance with Table-Valued Parameters - Dan Guzman](http://www.dbdelta.com/maximizing-performance-with-table-valued-parameters/)

---

An alternative to TVPs, you can **split** the `@innerstring` variable.

```
create procedure dbo.Select_Using_YearQuarter_Delimited (
    @DelimitedString nvarchar(256)
) as
begin;
  set nocount on;
  set xact_abort on;
  with c as (
    select ce.[Date] 
      from dbo.Calendar_Example ce  
        inner join dbo.DelimitedSplitN4k(@DelimitedString,';') as d 
          on convert(char(7),d.Item) = ce.YearQuarter
      )
  select *
    from MM
      inner join c  on mm.CDate = c.Date;
end;
go
```

The above example assumes a delimiter of ';', and uses [Jeff Moden's DelimitedSplitN4k](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) (comments removed, slightly reformatted).

```
create function dbo.DelimitedSplitN4K (
    @pString nvarchar(4000)
  , @pDelimiter nchar(1)
  )
returns table with schemabinding as
return
  with e1(n) as (
    select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all 
    select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all 
    select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1
  )
  , e2(n) as (select 1 from e1 a, e1 b)
  , e4(n) as (select 1 from e2 a, e2 b)
  , cteTally(n) as (select top (isnull(datalength(@pString)/2,0))
      row_number() over (order by (select null)) from e4)
  , cteStart(n1) as (select 1 union all 
      select t.n+1 from cteTally t where substring(@pString,t.n,1) = @pDelimiter)
  , cteLen(n1,l1) as(select s.n1
  ,   isnull(nullif(charindex(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.n1),0)-s.n1,4000)
    from cteStart s
  )
 select ItemNumber = row_number() over(order by l.n1)
      , Item       = substring(@pString, l.n1, l.l1)
   from cteLen l;
go
```

splitting strings reference:

- [Tally OH! An Improved SQL 8K “CSV Splitter” Function](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)
- [Splitting Strings : A Follow-Up - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-follow-up)
- [Split strings the right way – or the next best way](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)